# TMC2208,BMG and 0.9 degree stepper motor, is this a bad combination?

Tags: marlin, tmc2208

My printer randomly freezes partway into the print whenever I use the combination of Marlin 2.0, TMC2208 stealthchop, a 3:1 geared extruder and an E3D 0.9° stepper in a Bowden configuration on the E axis.

Is this a reasonable combination that other people have got working or is it too high of a step count (830 steps/mm) for this particular driver? If I change one of these factors it prints normally but not when they are all used together.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Maybe you could add your controller board make and model, printer type, e.g. Delta or i3?

Comment: [Cross post](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/jc1j00/anyone_using_a_09_degree_stepper_with_a_bmg_and/)?